# move images away before refresh browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael, reload

In a html page I am making, I dynamically move images into the viewport using jQuery and Raphael's library.  When I refresh the webpage, these images appears to be white block for <100ms before the webpage loads again.  I want to move these images out of the viewport so these white blocks don't appear.

I used `window.onbeforeuload=functio(){$('#myimge").css(...);}` to move the image.  But it turns out that the white blocks still appear because the browser doesn't have time to show a newly refreshed view with the images in the new location. If I put `alert()`, then the images will disappear.  So I am looking a way to really move the images out of the browser window before the browser reloads the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, you can't block window from closing, unless you hack it, but it's very bad practise i think

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
     var start = +new Date;
     while ((+new Date - start) < 3000);                        
 });
```

For me i would go with ajax loaded pages, more like HTML5 pages